# Run a multiline subprocess command in the background

Tags: python

I would like to run a script as a multiline comman in jupyter. This works using

```
import subprocess
script  = ''' mkdir folder1
              rm -r folder0
              touch folder1/fileX.txt
          '''
 
subprocess.run(script , shell=True)
```

However, in reality some of the lines in the script take quite some time and therefore, I need the entire scipt to run in the background.

I am not sure if there is a way, except to wite the skript into a file and execute the file from the direcotry like:

```
subprocess.run('./script &' , shell=True)
```

many thx for your ideas!
BR, maths

Comment: `{ command1; command 2; command 3; } &`

Comment: How about `{ command1; command2; command3; } &` with all spaces and semi-colons required.

Comment: @KamilCuk Snap :-)

Comment: Can you show how to exactly implement this in subprocess.run(). Writing the script as script = '{command1; command2; } &' in subprocess.run(script, shell=True) is not working

Comment: You need all the spaces as shown, and the the `bash` shell.

Comment: This works: script = 'command1; command2; command3;'-> subprocess.run(script, shell=True). However, not in the background. This script2 = '{ ' + script + ' } &' dose not work at all (all spaces are as shown?). FYI the commands are several calculations, but I think this should not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have the solution:
Thx for the usefule comments!

```
script = 'bash -c "command1; command2; command3; " &'
```

this works using `subprocess.run()`. I did not know that I have to define bash shell explicity.